# Golang. Как исправить ошибку "use of closed network connection"?

Tags: golang, cors, golang-gin

Разрабатываю api на языке golang используя фрэймворк gin. API сервер выдаёт информацию в виде JSON.

Запросы по http работают нормально. Но спустя пару запросов через ajax, я не могу больше брать информацию с сервера ни по url, ни через ajax.

Headers я так же указываю, как на сервере, так и на javascript.

Headers на api сервере:

```
r := gin.New()

r.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
    AllowOrigins:     []string{"*"},
    AllowMethods:     []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "HEAD"},
    AllowHeaders:     []string{"*"},
    ExposeHeaders:    []string{"*"},
    AllowCredentials: true,
    AllowOriginFunc: func(origin string) bool {
        return origin == "*"
    },
    MaxAge: 12 * time.Hour,
}))
```

API Сервер постоянно при запросе по url выдаёт данную ошибку:

```
read tcp 127.0.0.1:44188->127.0.0.1:5432: use of closed network connection
set tcp 127.0.0.1:44188: use of closed network connection
```

Логи контейнера:

```
2021-03-22 18:36:22.166 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.1 (Debian 13.1-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
2021-03-22 18:36:22.166 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2021-03-22 18:36:22.166 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2021-03-22 18:36:22.324 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-03-22 18:36:22.548 UTC [75] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-03-22 18:36:21 UTC
2021-03-22 18:36:22.628 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2021-03-22 19:37:28.737 UTC [204] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2021-03-22 19:37:50.508 UTC [205] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2021-03-22 19:42:53.344 UTC [213] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2021-03-22 20:06:24.316 UTC [218] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

Как исправить данную проблему?

Comment: может контейнер перезагружается?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor контейнер чего?

Comment: как я вижу ваш api server работает с постгрей. и вот соединение сервера с посгрес оборвался. я бы копал в этом месте. а мапинг портов похож на работу с докером. поэтому пишу, что может быть контейнер перезагружается?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor а, понял. Ну да, у меня postgresql запущен на docker, но вот вопрос, если перегружается контейнер, то как это исправить?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor И вообще, точно ли только в контейнере проблема? Потому что read tcp 127.0.0.1:44188->127.0.0.1:5432: use of closed network connection выводит только один раз, а вот set tcp 127.0.0.1:44188: use of closed network connection выводит каждый раз, когда обращаешься по url api сервера.

Comment: надо понять почему перезагружается. посмотрите логи контейнера

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121147/discussion-between-yeahyeahcore-and-senior-pomidor).

Comment: @SeniorPomidor добавил логи в содержание вопроса.

Comment: Это сообщение указывает на то, что клиент (ваше приложение) закрыло связь. Почему - вам нужно выяснить, может быть непойманная ошибка, к примеру. Лог приложения указывает что вы пытаетесь выводить что-то еще после отсылки ответа. Приведите минимальный код того, как у вас устроен сервер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все вызовы `row.Scan()` должны быть проверены на наличие ошибок.

я добавил ошибки и обнаружил сообщение `conn is busy` и после уже `use of closed network connection`.
pgx.Connect() возвращает pgx.Conn который не может работать для параллельных запросов. Документация [говорит](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx#Conn).

> Conn is a PostgreSQL connection handle. It is not safe for concurrent
> usage. Use a connection pool to manage access to multiple database
> connections from multiple goroutines.

поэтому заменяем `pgx.Connect()` на `pgxpool.Connect()` из `github.com/jackc/pgx/pgxpool`.